# Take the value of an object in an object

Tags: javascript

I have something like this:

```
var list = {
        "number": 43,
        "text1": "text1",
        "text2": [{
            "text3": "text3",
            "text4": "text4"
        }]
    };
```

I want to take back the value of text4. However when I type list.text2.text4 in console I can't take back anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `text2` is an array. You need to update from

```
list.text2.text4
```

to

```
list.text2[0].text4
```

Answer (score 1):

Though text2 is an array. you need provide index for that. check it.

```
list.text2[0].text4
```